# Is there any method to make almost an automatic 'hive'?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm trying to do something like in the picture,

[image]

Which is a grid made of hexagons, like a 'hive'.

I  could generate a texture in another software like PS to add it, but what i want is to extrude upwards the yellow part, so the black parts are in depth.

How can i do this, using the options of Blender, without having to model it completely? i was thinking on making one hexagon and then duplicate it infinitely, but i think there should be another way for this.

Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with 6-sided cylinders, and array modifiers:

- 1st modifier to create a duplicate at a diagonal offset (x:0.5, y:0.766 )
- 2nd modifier for 1 row in say the x-direction (x:.667, and not 1, as the boundig box covers both the cylinders)
- 3rd modifier to fill the plane in the y direction (y:0.857)

Then I'd either apply the modifiers and remove unwanted geometry, or use boolean modifiers to create holes where I want them (or to limit the structure to a given volume).

The black grooves can be a simple plane, or you can slighty modify the initial cylinder (and/or adapt the array offsets if needed) by extruding the lower set of edges outward. Close the other end of the basic cylinder for the yellow plates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent-enough Blender, go to File > User Preferences > Add-Ons tab, and activate Add Mesh: Extra Objects.

Now, under <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > Mesh > Extras, you will find a parameterised 'Honeycomb' option.

(If you want simple edges to extrude, set 'Edge Thickness' to 0, and remove doubles.)